Recursively delete empty files and then empty directories
The following script non-recursively deletes regular empty files, not including the dot ones, and then non-recursively deletes empty directories, not including the dot ones, and ignoring the presence of .DS_Store files (that is, if the directory contains only a .DS_Store file, that directory will be nevertheless deleted).
rm -f -- *(.L0)

setopt extended_glob
has_files_other_than_DS_Store() [[ -n $REPLY/^(#i).ds_store(#qNDY1) ]]
remove_empty_macos_dirs() {
  local dir ret=0
  for dir do
    rm -f -- $dir/.(#i)ds_store(N.) && rmdir -- $dir || ret=$?
  done
  return $ret
}
remove_empty_macos_dirs *(/^+has_files_other_than_DS_Store)

Could somebody show how to make it work recursively? That is, the first step is to recursively delete all the empty regular files. And then recursively delete empty directories.
I would try it myself, but to be honest I simply afraid to experiment with the rm command.

Note that there are questions here at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange that seem to be similar at the first glance, but actualy they are about using bash or find. My question is not a duplicate.

The replies in https://stackoverflow.com/q/78852512/3387716 may help a little bit

The best way to experiment with the building of such a script without risk is to first build you an artificial test tree:
dir1nonemptycontaining: file1nonempty,file2empty,.DS_Store,dir2,dir3empty
with dir2 only containing .DS_Store
and dir3empty realy empty.

To do that recursively, you'd need to do it depth first, so that if for instance dirA contains only dirB, itself empty, you delete dirB first so that dirA then becomes empty and can be deleted in turn.
zsh globs do have the od qualifier for depth-first ordering:
set -o extendedglob
zmodload zsh/files # get builtin rm/rmdir for improved performance
                   # and also avoid E2BIG limits of their standalone
                   # equivalents
rmall() {
  # annoyingly zsh's rm builtin complains if not given any argument
  # even with -f
  (( $# == 0 )) || rm -f -- "$@"
}
ret=0
rmall **/*(ND.L0) # remove empty regular files first
for dir (**/*(ND/od)) ()(($#)) $dir/^(#i).ds_store(NDY1) || {
  rmall $dir/.(#i)ds_store(N.) && rmdir -- $dir || ret=$?
}

You can replace rm/rmdir with print -r Would rm/print -r Would rmdir to test first, but that will not necessarily have the same effect as print won't delete any files so cannot render directories empty.
